# RMysql dbWriteTable Error infinite recursion

Tags: r, ubuntu, rmysql

I am trying to use dbWriteTable to store a data frame into MySQL database. Here is the code:

```
mydb = getDbConnect(courseSlug)
dbWriteTable(mydb, name = table_name, value = dataframe, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE , 
           field.types = list(col1 = "varchar(5)",col2 = "bigint",Visits = "bigint"
           ,col3 = "bigint",col4 = "bigint",`col 5` = "double",`col 6` = "double")) 
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

It perfectly works in my local machine:

- R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
- Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

However, I get the following error

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)?

in the AWS server machine which has R with following specifications:

- R version 3.3.0 beta (2016-03-30 r70404)
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Would you help me what the issue might be?